# is there function for sum with no overlapping, by month and lineNum?

Tags: sql-server

Can you help me please.
I have one table with pkid, linNum, dateStart, dateStop, month.
i need to sum the time with non overlap , by lineNum over dateMonth.
how much lineNum 1,2 on month 10, and month 11 ?

```
pkid  lineNum          dateStart                dateStop              dateMonth

1        1        2019-11-06 13:07:21.400     2019-11-06 14:07:21.400    2019-10-01

2        1        019-11-06 14:07:21.400     2019-11-06 18:07:21.400    2019-10-01

3        1        2019-11-06 11:07:21.400     2019-11-06 11:27:21.400    2019-10-01

4        1        2019-11-06 14:07:21.400     2019-11-06 19:07:21.400    2019-10-01

5        2        2019-11-06 10:07:21.400     2019-11-06 17:07:21.400    2019-10-01

6        2        2019-11-06 09:07:21.400     2019-11-06 17:07:21.400    2019-10-01

7        2        2019-11-06 07:07:21.400     2019-11-06 17:07:21.400    2019-10-01

8        1        2019-11-06 11:07:21.400     2019-11-06 17:07:21.400    2019-11-01

9        1        2019-11-06 17:07:21.400     2019-11-06 22:07:21.400    2019-11-01

10       1        2019-11-06 19:07:21.400     2019-11-06 23:07:21.400    2019-11-01

15       1        2019-11-06 19:07:21.400     2019-11-06 23:07:21.400    2019-11-02
```

Comment: By 'sum time' you mean Difference between max date and min date in hours and minutes or days? What does sum of the time means?

Comment: Kelevra, yes sum  of hours with non overlapping

Comment: What do you mean by non-overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing a `SUM` with a `GROUP BY`.

IE

```
SELECT SUM (lineNum) 
FROM table
GROUP BY dateMonth;
```

This SHOULD give you a result of `10` for **2019-10-01**

That said .. You SHOULD be using `DATETIME` as your field and formatting like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as your other fields are, then you can use terms like `MONTH` in a `WHERE` clause --

```
SELECT SUM (lineNum) 
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(dateMonth) = '10';
```

Furthering that .. You can choose Month and Year --  IE

```
SELECT SUM (lineNum) 
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(dateMonth) = '10'
AND YEAR(dateMonth) = '2019';
```

Here is a simple [REFERENCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) on working with dates in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code. It will calculate the difference in minutes between DateStart and DateStop in `CTE` and then sum them together in the next query using `GROUP BY`

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE( pkid int, lineitem int, dateStart Datetime, dateStop Datetime, dateMonth Date)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (pkid, lineitem, dateStart, DateStop, dateMonth)
values(1, 1, '2019-11-06 13:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 14:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(2, 1, '2019-11-06 14:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 18:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(3, 1, '2019-11-06 11:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 11:27:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(4, 1, '2019-11-06 14:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 19:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(5, 2, '2019-11-06 10:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 17:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(6, 2, '2019-11-06 09:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 17:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(7, 2, '2019-11-06 07:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 17:07:21.400', '2019-10-01'),
(8, 1, '2019-11-06 11:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 17:07:21.400', '2019-11-01'),
(9, 1, '2019-11-06 17:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 22:07:21.400', '2019-11-01'),
(10, 1,'2019-11-06 19:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 23:07:21.400', '2019-11-01'),
(15, 1,'2019-11-06 19:07:21.400', '2019-11-06 23:07:21.400', '2019-11-02');


WITH CTE AS (
SELECT LINEITEM,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATESTART, DATESTOP) AS TIMEDIFF,
       DATEPART(MONTH, DATEMONTH) AS DATEMONTH
FROM @MYTABLE
)
SELECT LINEITEM,
       SUM(TIMEDIFF) AS TIMEDIFF,
       DATEMONTH
FROM CTE
GROUP BY LINEITEM, DATEMONTH
```

Results

```
LINEITEM   TIMEDIFF   DATEMONTH
1           620          10
2           1500         10
1           1140         11
```

Comment: Sorry , i explained wrong ,  that way just adds max and min. I need lineNum 1 from October 390 min. line Num 2 from October 600 min.

Comment: What 600 min represents? If you need minutes then change HOUR to MINUTE

Comment: sum pkid 1 until pkid 4 , yes hour to minute

Comment: Can you please provide desired outcome, so I can understand clearly

Comment: (1:07 - 2:07      60 min 
2:07 - 18:07     240 min
11:07 - 11:27    30 min 
2:07   -19:07    300 min 
line 1 Total For october is 60 + 30 + 300 = 390 min  )                                                                                              
(10:07 - 17:07  420 min 
09:07 - 17:07  480 min 
07:07 - 17:07   600 min 
line 2 Total For October is 600 min ) 
(11:07 - 12:07  60 min 
17:07- 22:07  300 min 
19:07 - 23:07   240 min
15:07 - 22:07  420 min 
line 1 total for novemeber is 60 + 480 = 540 min)

Comment: I tryed but result month 10 = 620 , i need month 10 = 380 , because 1:07 - 2:07      60 min 
2:07 - 18:07     240 min
11:07 - 11:27    20 min 
2:07   -19:07    300 min 

line 1 Total For october is 60 + 30 + 300 = 380 min, i need sum for October and November group by  lineNum, dateMonth.

Comment: this i'm trying to must be an overlap

Comment: I don't know your business logic and I don't understand your terms of overlapping. Please elaborate it more clearly in your question so at least I have some idea about it. What makes pkid 2 an overlap? Why 240 min do not get included in the calculation?

Comment: Because its is between 02:07 from pkid 1 and 19:07 from pkid 4

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, provide a more comprehensive desired outcome and the query that you have already tried